# Can we call extension functions from page scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a function in my extension:

```
function doStuff() {
  // Do stuff
}
```

I'd like to call it from a script on the page:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Extension Test</title>
    <script>doStuff();</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>This is a test.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, I'm getting an error in the Console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: doStuff is not defined at (index):6

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Use a separate js file. More info: [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](//stackoverflow.com/a/25721457)

Comment: @wOxxOm ~ I couldn't get that to work. I still get `doStuff is not defined`. But I've abandoned my Chrome extension approach for the problem at hand, so the question is no longer applicable at the present time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you have to add the following code in the `manifest.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "http://*/", "https://*/" ],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/"
  ]
  ...
}
```

now you should create a `content.js` file whose content is:

```js
const injectedScript = document.createElement('script');
injectedScript.src = chrome.extension.getURL('injected.js');
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(injectedScript);
```

Then create an injected.js file and write your code in this file, such as:

```js
function doStuff() {
  // Do stuff
}
```

i hope I understand what you mean. If there is a problem, please let me know.

Comment: That looks like it should work. In the meantime, however, I discovered another—and much easier—answer to the problem I'm trying to solve, that doesn't involve a Chrome extension at all. That's a relief, for me at least, because this would have been my first such project. I wasn't looking forward to yet another deviation along this path. Nevertheless, I'm marking yours as the answer because it looks like it should work.